# use headphone output as mic input on a mac

Tags: audio, microphone, macos-sonoma

I downloaded blackhole 2ch on my mac.
I am trying to set it up so that when I have a meeting with a client I can hear them and talk to them just fine(as usual). However, I want to also use my headphone output (what the client is saying / what I am hearing) as audio input in a transcription software so I can provide it for them after the meeting.

i got blackhole downloaded and tried different combinations but couldn't get it working.

Comment: What different combinations did you try? Is the headphone output CAPABLE of mic input? What is outputting the signal you're trying to route to the input? Can't you record the session just directly on the computer, without having to deal with outputting and inputting?

Comment: Install  [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) then use two headphones as [described here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/output-mac-audio-two-pairs-headphones/)

Comment: @music2myear good questions. I will have to more carefully check the first part of what you said. I though i understood it well, but your questions are making me reconsider. as for the second thing, I kinda need it to work in real-time since i provide feedback based on what their talking about in real-time sometimes.

Comment: @1NN not super elegant, but this might be a good solution until i can find something better. i will try it out today